# First load blank white page into PDF Viewer using github.barteksc

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf, pdf-viewer

I have used below lib for view PDF file into my application.

```
 implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
```

But I am facing one issue is it is showing first blank white page then after load actual PDF file.
I have do some R&D for the same but couldn't fine any solution.

Is there any another Lib?

Comment: @KJ pdf is loading from the local database.